# Cannot enable SSL, apache service won't start when default-ssl.conf changed

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

Here's the `journalctl -xe` result of this error. This is not happening when I replace default-ssl.conf with default one.

```
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up. 
Kas 06 00:55:42 XCH apachectl[25161]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message 
Kas 06 00:55:42 XCH apachectl[25161]: Action 'start' failed. 
Kas 06 00:55:42 XCH apachectl[25161]: The Apache error log may have more information. 
Kas 06 00:55:42 XCH systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1 
Kas 06 00:55:42 XCH systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
Kas 06 00:55:42 XCH systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

`journalctl | tail` results are all [UFW BLOCK] lines with mac and ip information.

I simply follow any reference and tutorial on internet but this keeps happening only to me I guess. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you blindly follow stuff from the Internet, you're doomed. Your life will be filled with confusion and failure.

However, a careful reading of "`Kas 06 00:55:42 XCH apachectl[25161]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`" should tell you that there's a problem around the `ServerName` directive in your modified  `default-ssl.conf`. Did you have a working `apache2` configuration before you did this?

Comment: FYI that's a non-critical warning, and not a major error.  Why it's failing to work properly may need more debugging, it could be an SSL issue or certificates not being defined right, or something along those lines.